# How to Require Different Sections of a Word Document be Approved by Different Approvers?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I have a current requirement for a document editing process that requires different sections of a Word document to be reviewed and approved by different parties before being deemed "acceptable" to progress to the next step in the process.  For example, section #1 of the document needs to be approved by approver #1, and section #2 of the document needs to be approved by section #2, etc.  Is there a Microsoft tool - Word, Power Automate, Microsoft Forms, Microsoft Team, SharePoint, or something else - that can be configured to handle this requirement?

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You have far more experience here than I do but this seems off-topic. Anyway, the only method I can think of is to actually divide the sections into separate documents.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesKenyon .  The scenario I am outlining is useful when I deal with large 100+ page documents, and certain parties only need to read a small section of the overall document.  Having separate documents is fine; however it makes things a little messy, since someone needs to collate it all once multiple parties have approved each document.